# Splitting Multi-page Tiff into Single Tiff's on Windows 7 / .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, tiff

I recently moved to a new development box from Windows XP 32 Bit to Windows 7 64 bit. Both machines are running .Net Framework version 4.0 for development with Visual Studio 2010.

After upgrading to Windows 7 64 Bit, my code to split a multi-page Tiff image into separate images is now broken (worked fine previously on XP 32 Bit, except for the MS fill order bug).  After debugging, the Bitmap Metadata appears to be read correctly by the .Net Framework, however, some component in the stack is incorrectly persisting the some Tiff Tags (273, 278, and 279).  I have tried several methods to accomplish the split, including GDI+, and the FreeImage library, but all fail within .Net.  I was able to successful split the Tiff using Image Magick and another 3rd party tool with valid tag values.

Specifically, Tiff Tags 273, 278 (should match 257 but does not), and 279 have incorrect values.

Is this a known Microsoft issue? Is there a workaround? Am I doing this task wrong? Very frustrated as this was working on XP 32 just fine and that OS is not a deployment option.

```
// Copy bytes into our memory
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(ms))
    {
        // Get the multi page tiff image's size, and allocate a place to put it.
        int size = RdmInstance.ImageSize;
        byte[] imgContents = new byte[size + 1];

        // Create the pointer and assign the Rdm image address to it
        IntPtr pointerToImage = new IntPtr(RdmInstance.ImageData);

        // Copy the bytes from unmanaged memory to managed memory
        Marshal.Copy(pointerToImage, imgContents, 0, size);

        // Now, write that contents into our memory stream
        bw.Write(imgContents);


        // Check for multiple tiff pages, split them out and write them out correctly for the Fed
        TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);

        if (decoder.Frames.Count > 0)
        {

            // check for multi page tiff
            for (int i = 0; i < decoder.Frames.Count; i++)
            {
                log.InfoFormat("Loading Multi Page Tiff Frame [{0}]... to bitmap", i);

                // First is front, second is back 
                // TODO - it would be better to get this out of tiff tag RDM sets with the page info
                string fileName = (i == 0) ? frontFileName : backFileName;
                BitmapSource bmSrc = decoder.Frames[i];
                TiffBitmapEncoder encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();

                encoder.Compression = TiffCompressOption.Ccitt4;
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmSrc));

                log.InfoFormat("Saving Multi Page Tiff Frame [{0}]... to file {1}.", i, fileName);
                using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    encoder.Save(fs);
                }

                /*
                 * jknipp - 6/4/2010 
                 * Microsoft has a bug in their TiffBitmapEncoder where
                 * they incorrectly set tag 266 (Fill Order) to 0, where the TIFF
                 * spec says it should be 1 or 2. We fix this here.
                 * Reopen the stupid file and fix the fill order
                 */
                using (var file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    TiffBitmapDecoder output = new TiffBitmapDecoder(file, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
                    InPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter metadata = output.Frames[0].CreateInPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter();

                    var fillOrder = metadata.GetQuery("/ifd/{ushort=266}");
                    log.DebugFormat("Read Fill Order Metadata tag as {0}", fillOrder);

                    // If .Net added a bogus fill order, correct it
                    if (fillOrder != null && (ushort)fillOrder == 0)
                    {
                        log.InfoFormat("Correcting FILL ORDER in file {0}", fileName);
                        metadata.SetQuery("/ifd/{ushort=266}", (ushort)1);

                        // Try to save new metadata
                        if (metadata.TrySave())
                        {
                            fillOrder = metadata.GetQuery("/ifd/{ushort=266}");
                            log.Info("Fill order correction successful!");
                            log.DebugFormat("Read New Fill Order Metadata tag as {0}", fillOrder);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [LibTiff.Net](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) library for this. It's free and open-source (BSD License).

The library comes with tiffcp utility that can be used from your code for splitting/merging TIFF images. Or you can use source code of that utility as a sample.

LibTiff.Net also contains samples for merging and splitting TIFF images using tiffcp from your application.

Disclaimer: I am one of the maintainers of the library.

Comment: I had looked at using LibTiff.Net yesterday, but decided to be lazy.  After hacking the TiffCP code into my application, it is working again!

Comment: Great that LibTiff.Net helped you :-)

Answer (score 3):

Judging from your initial code, my answer here may be naive with respect for your specific needs, but nonetheless, it works for me:

```
public static MyImage New(string filePath, ImageFormat imageFormat, 
    int imageSequence = 0)
{
    byte[] imageBytes;

    using (FileStream imageStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        Image tmpImg = Image.FromStream(imageStream);
        if (imageSequence > 0)
        {
            tmpImg.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, imageSequence);
        }
        imageBytes = ToByteArray(tmpImg, imageFormat);
        //FileStream must be open for entire lifetime of the Image
        imageStream.Close();
    }
    return new MyImage(filePath, imageBytes);
}

public static byte[] ToByteArray(Image image, ImageFormat imageFormat)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(ms, imageFormat);
        byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
        ms.Close();
        return bytes;
    }
}
```